# GPO applied but only 1 program run on 4

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have an issue that I can't explain with the GPO. I use the :

> User **>** Administration model **>** System **>** Session login **>** Run program
>   **>** when user login

(Approximately, my server is in French.)

So, when I run the "rsop.msc" on the computer, I can see that the GPO is correctly applied.

But on these 4 programs, the only program that is launched is notepad.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

---

**Windows Server** : 2008 R2 - 
**Client** : Windows 10 IoT (Update 1804)

Comment: The path to iexplore.exe is incorrect.  The path to "x3" isn't even an executable.  I can't read French. You should provide a translation to the text within your screenshot.

Comment: My educated guess is that this list is processed in sequence. Close Notepad and check what happens.

Comment: @Ramhound, "Afficher le contenu : Display content" , "Valeur : Value" , "Elements à executer... : Program to execute when open session".

Comment: @DanielB, I tried, but nothing appened, I already check the task manager to be sure.

Comment: When I suggested you provide a translation.  I mean within the question body, and/or within the image itself, allowing the commentary section to remain spick and span.

Comment: I changed the path of iexplorer, who worked know. But Sage x3 does't work.. :/

Comment: I don't know why but I re-make the GPO and it works now ..

Thanks.